# C# newbie with DateTime variable I want to set to null

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, nullable

I have an output data class with a DateTime variable. I want to clear that to a null value in a loader class but the compiler complains with:

> Cannot convert null to 'System.Data.Time' because it is a non-nullable value type.

I understand that, but if I change the type to DateTime? creating the nullable type wrapper I get:

> No overload for method 'ToString' takes '1' arguments

I have an output line that reads.

> ACCOUNT_ESTABLISHED_DATE.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")

So the question is, when I set the DateTime as nullable, how do I get around the fact that is no longer behaves like a DateTime that has the formatted ToString available?

Answer (score 8):

Use its Value property, like so:

```
DateTime? dt = DateTime.Now; // or whatever
MessageBox.Show(dt.Value.ToString(...));
```

Comment: Remember to account for the possibility of `dt.HasValue == false`

Comment: Its so much easier in Java. But Thanks, I did use

ACCOUNT_ESTABLISHED_DATE == null ? " " : ACCOUNT_ESTABLISHED_DATE.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")

to clear the issue

Answer (score 2):

try

```
ACCOUNT_ESTABLISHED_DATE.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
```

You need to access the actual value using the 'Value' property of the nullable type.

You should make sure 'Value' contains something first testing the ACCOUNT_ESTABLISHED_DATE.HasValue property.

HTH

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you wrap something `Nullable<>` (which is what you're doing with `DateTime?`), you need to do `obj.Value.ToString()`.

Answer (score 1):

are you looking for

```
DateTime? dt = new DateTime();
```

or

```
Nullable<DateTime> dt = new DateTime();
ACCOUNT_ESTABLISHED_DATE.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Answer (score 1):

You should write:

```
ACCOUNT_ESTABLISHED_DATE.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
```

Answer (score 1):

.NET doesn't have a method out of the box for this. You'd need to have a helper method like:

```
public string Format(DateTime? date, string format)
{
    if (date == null)
        return string.Empty;

    return date.Value.ToString(format);
}
```

Or even better, an extension method for `DateTime?`:

```
public static class DateTimeExtensionMethods
{
    public static string ToString(this DateTime? date, string format)
    {
        if (date == null)
            return string.Empty;

        return date.Value.ToString(format);
    }
}
```

Then to use your extension method, just use the code you have in your question and make sure the namespace of the `DateTimeExtensionMethods` is imported into your class.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use

```
dt.HasValue ? dt.Value.ToString("...") : dt.ToString();
```

This is because `Nullable<T>` is a proper type in its own right whose `ToString()` method is already nicely done, as it handles the `null` case well. But to get to the underlying non-nullable object you have to use the `Value` property. But then you'll have to check for `null` (or `HasValue`) yourself.

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime? date = getSomeDate();
if (date != null) {
   date.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at setting the DateTime to DataTime.MinValue?

Suggested here http://dotnetperls.com/datetime-null-minvalue

Answer (score 0):

```
  string strDate = string.Empty;
  if(ACCOUNT_ESTABLISHED_DATE != null)
  {
  strDate = ACCOUNT_ESTABLISHED_DATE.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
 }

  or you can use null collacing operator

  DateTime newDate  = ACCOUNT_ESTABLISHED_DATE ?? new Date();

   newDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```